# invalidating session across all application in weblogic 11g

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic11g

I am new to weblogic and am porting over a series of web applications from jboss. I have multiple war's that I deploy to the same weblogic server. All of them are configured for Form based authentication backed by active directory.

I'm having issues logging out of the applications however. I have one of the applications that serves as my login application that contains the actual login.jsp form. It also has a logout servlet that calls session.invalidate(). After calling this, i can't access protected pages in the main application, but can access protected pages in the other applications.

From what I've been reading, weblogic 11g shares the same session across all applications, which makes sense with what I am seeing. I'm finding references to using the following to invalidate a session across all applications:

```
invalidateAll(HttpServletRequest req)
```

in package

```
weblogic.servlet.security.ServletAuthentication
```

However, I can not find this or anything similar in weblogic 11g. Where is this utility class or how should I be doing this?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Based on Josek's answer below, I had to add the following to my weblogic.xml file for all of the applications that I am deploying:

```
 <session-descriptor>
     <sharing-enabled>true</sharing-enabled>
 </session-descriptor>
```

The jar that I was looking for is called wls-api.jar that contains the ServletAuthentication class. I was using the zip based 10.3.3.0 version of the web logic server. I found the jar in the installation of the wlserver_10.3 server installation as part of the Weblogic Fusion installation. I just took the jar and added it to our Nexus maven repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`invalidateAll`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/javadocs/weblogic/servlet/security/ServletAuthentication.html#invalidateAll%28HttpServletRequest%29) is documented as part of WLS 10.3 (aka 11g) so it should work in your logout servlet. Have you tried it and faced any error?

> It also has a logout servlet that
>   calls session.invalidate(). After
>   calling this, i can't access protected
>   pages in the main application, but can
>   access protected pages in the other
>   applications

This indicates to me, that the sessions are **not** shared across web applications, which is the default behaviour. If the sessions were shared the user would be logged out of all the applications. For the sessions to be shared, you would have to set [`sharing-enabled`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13712/weblogic_xml.htm#i1071981)
to true

As [the docs state](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13712/sessions.htm#i104405),

> By default, Web applications do not
>   share the same session. If you would
>   like Web applications to share the
>   same session, you can configure the
>   session descriptor at the application
>   level in the weblogic-application.xml
>   deployment descriptor. To enable Web
>   applications to share the same
>   session, set the sharing-enabled
>   attribute in the session descriptor to
>   true in the weblogic-application.xml
>   deployment descriptor.

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. The problem with invalidateAll is that I can't find the jar file that contains that method. I will try setting the sharing enabled attribute. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, everything is working. See above for solution based on your answer.

Comment: this might work with multiple `war` deployed under weblogic app server. What if we have multiple `ear` deployed in weblogic.  
those are accessed as `hostname.com/webapp1` and `hostname.com/app2`

As usual oracle doc hass not clearly mentioned `weblogic-application.xml` or `weblogic.xml` 

or may be I am not clear with difference among them.